# cipher python not returning right

Tags: python, encryption

not getting right outcome and need assistance with decipher code

```
# need help with code
cipher = ''
decipher = ''
choice = ''
while choice != 0:
    choice = input('Press 1 to encrypt your text \nPress 2 to decrypt your 
    cipher text \n:')
    if choice == '1':
        cipher = input('Enter text to encrypt').lower()
        for letter in cipher:
            if(letter != ''):
                cipher += the_bacon[letter]
        print(cipher)
    break
```

```
>>> Press 1 to encrypt your text 
>>> Press 2 to decrypt your cipher text 
:1
>>> Enter text to encrypt
hello world
hello worldaabbb
hello worldaabbbaabaa
hello worldaabbbaabaaababb
hello worldaabbbaabaaababbababb
hello worldaabbbaabaaababbababbabbba
```

need to create substitution bacon cipher and its not working properly , need help with decipher code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `the_bacon` is a proper dictionary with 1 to 1 letter swaps, your problem is that you are appending on the input instead of creating a new output object and then printing that.

You can also use `while not choice:` to represent to loop until they answer. `!= 0` will never happen unless you were going to turn it into an `int` type first.

```py
cipher = ''
decipher = ''
choice = ''
while not choice:
    choice = input('Press 1 to encrypt your text \nPress 2 to decrypt your 
    cipher text \n:')
    if choice == '1':
        in_cipher = input('Enter text to encrypt').lower()
        out_cipher = ''
        for letter in in_cipher:
            if(letter != ' '):
                out_cipher += the_bacon[letter]
                print(out_cipher) # print output letter by letter as it builds
        print(out_cipher) # print the output
    else:
        # you need to decipher here and handle choices not 1 or 2
```